# XML form related fields

Tags: jquery, form, joomla-3.6, form-fields-types, xml

I need to make a form with dependent fields.
I have already tried a lot of options, but have not found the right way.
As in the picture below, I'm trying to load a new XML file when you select an option from the list.

[image]

When the first list, select "Option 1" in the form of outputting a field from a file "file1.xml" in which other standard field Joomla.

Perhaps the answer is very simple, but I was very tired and cant find it.

Comment: Please progress this page toward a system-recognized resolution. If you still require support, please ask for it by editing your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use [Subform field](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/7829)?. It allows you to nest XML forms inside each other or reuse your existing forms inside your current form. And your need, you can combine it with [showon](https://docs.joomla.org/form_field#Showon) attribute.